# product best dynamic menu 3 label php mysqli

Tags: php, html

i have i issue 3rd lebel menu not print but main menu and sub menu are working so please help me

table name "romtech"

1. categories ->cat_id,categories_name;
2. sub_categories  ->sub_id , cat_id, sub_categories_name;
3. sub_child_categories ->ch_id , sub_id , cat_id, child_categories_name;

PHP code

```
<div class="cat_menu_container">
    <div class="cat_menu_title d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
        <div class="cat_burger"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
        <div class="cat_menu_text">categories</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="cat_menu">
        <!-----------------------sql error set liimit 5 and order by desc not working please check its sir---------------------------->
        <?php $menu=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_status='1' and order by cat_id limit 5"); while($row=$menu->fetch_array()){?>
        <li class="hassubs"><a href="categories.php?cat_id=<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['categories_name']; ?><i class="fas fa-chevron-right ml-auto"></i></a>


            <!-----------Second ------------------>
            <?php $sub=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_categories WHERE sub_cat_status ='1' and cat_id=".$row['cat_id']);?>
            <ul> 
                <?php while($menu_row=$sub->fetch_array()){ ?>
                <li class="hassubs"><a href="categories.php?sub_id=<?php echo $menu_row['sub_id']; ?>"><?php echo $menu_row['sub_categories_name']; ?><i class="fas fa-chevron-right ml-auto"></i></a>


                    <!-----------third -issue part----------------->
                    <?php $child=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_child_categories WHERE sub_id =".$row['sub_id'] AND cat_id =.$row['cat_id']);?>
                    <ul> 
                        <?php while($child_row=$child->fetch_array()){ ?>
                        <li class="hassubs"><a href="categories.php?sub_id=<?php echo $child_row['ch_id']; ?>"><?php echo $child_row['child_categories_name']; ?><i class="fas fa-chevron-right ml-auto"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </ul>

                    <!-----------third ----end-------------->


                </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
          <!-----------Second ----end-------------->


        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: check its now sir

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: third chird menu not print

Comment: my code is <?php $child=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_child_categories WHERE sub_id =".$row['sub_id'] AND cat_id =.$row['cat_id']);?>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')' in D:\xammp\htdocs\romtech\header.php on line 127

Comment: Which line is 127?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')' in D:\xammp\htdocs\romtech\header.php on line 127

Comment: sub_id =".$row['sub_id'] AND sub_id =.$row['sub_id']);?>

Comment: <!-----------third ------------------>

Comment: use sub_id =".$menu_row ['sub_id']

Comment: <?php $child=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_child_categories WHERE sub_id =".$menu_row ['sub_id'] AND cat_id =.$row['cat_id']);?>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')' in D:\xammp\htdocs\romtech\header.php on line 127

Comment: accepting the answer is a good habit, this will help to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

third level query is

```
$child=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_child_categories WHERE sub_id =".$menu_row['sub_id']."");
```

Use

```
`sub_id =".$menu_row ['sub_id']`
```

OR

```
 `sub_id =".$menu_row ['sub_id']` AND cat_id=$row['cat_id']`
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')' in D:\xammp\htdocs\romtech\header.php on line 127

Comment: child=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_child_categories WHERE sub_id =".$menu_row['sub_id']."?");

Comment: <?php $child=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM sub_child_categories WHERE sub_id =".$menu_row['sub_id']."");?>

Comment: if it is help full for you please right  check on this answer

Comment: ("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_status='1' and oder by cat_id limiit 5"); is not working sir

Comment: remove and before order by